# Finding the inverse of a discrete function

Tags: c

Given the map how would I go about finding the inverse of this map so f(25) = 0 and so on in C. Any pointers to help me go forward in the right direction

```
i f(i)
0 25
1 11
2 24
3 0
4 19
5 2 
6 7 
7 15
8 27
9 14
10 17
11 22
12 13
13 26
14 20
15 16
16 8
17 10
18 18
19 4
20 12
22 23
23 3
24 5
25 21
26 6
27 1
```

Comment: How are you storing the current map ?

Comment: I'm only storing f[i] in an array I don't store i anywhere

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming that the map is bijective, so every key appears exactly once as a value and every value appears exactly once as a key).

As a hint, think about what would happen if you created a second array, then indexed into that array using the values from the old array.

Comment: Yes its a one to one function.